# Facing issue with firebase bitcode : App store denied my .net maui app how to resolve it

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I want to add my app on app store but the test flight denied my app because of following issue

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/FirebaseInstallations.framework/FirebaseInstallations' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/FirebaseMessaging.framework/FirebaseMessaging' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/GoogleAPIClientForREST.framework/GoogleAPIClientForREST' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/GoogleDataTransport.framework/GoogleDataTransport' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/Protobuf.framework/Protobuf' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/leveldb.framework/leveldb' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/nanopb.framework/nanopb' contains bitcode.

Comment: I have tried above code lines but show the following error 

The command "/Users/apple/Downloads/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Users/apple/.nuget/packages/harfbuzzsharp.nativeassets.ios/2.8.2.3/runtimes/ios/native/libHarfBuzzSharp.framework/libHarfBuzzSharp -r -o /Users/apple/.nuget/packages/harfbuzzsharp.nativeassets.ios/2.8.2.3/runtimes/ios/native/libHarfBuzzSharp.framework/libHarfBuzzSharp" exited with code 127. (MSB3073) 


Please provide me a appropriate solution